# Android Studio, Kotlin shows error in variable declaration

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Why does it show an error here? (The red underline)
[image]

Saw it from a youtube video, copied it literally, does not work. Help appreciated thanks. Im wondering if it is an issue of a version mismatch?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Please provide a copy of your code. Screenshots are not searchable.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, if you hover your mouse pointer over the red squiggles, the IDE will tell you what is wrong.

In this case, the root cause appears to be that you are trying to use Kotlin syntax in a Java class.

Comment: Thank you, could you tell me how can I switch it to a kotlin class?

Comment: @NInadKulkarni: The details will vary by IDE and version. In Android Studio, if you right-click over the file in the project tree, you should see a "Convert Java File to Kotlin File" option, which will attempt to convert the class for you. Or, if this is a brand-new project, throw it out and create another new project where you choose Kotlin as your primary language.

Answer (score 0):

because you file is .java and you can not write kotlin code in java file.